# Получить id и классы из строки по регулярному выражению в PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите сделать разбор строки на id и классы.
Так не выходит, он понимает только первый разбор или id или класс, а дальше ступор.

```
$str = ".cl_name.cl_name2#send.cl_name3"
preg_match('/(^#(?P<id>.+?)[\s|\.])?(\.(?P<class>.+?)[\s|\.|#])?/is', $str, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Comment: `preg_match_all()` и дальше перебор массива результатов http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php И на четвертый параметр функции обратите внимание.

Comment: @Vismanслишком замудрено получается и он не находит все классы, кроме этого я думаю, что есть решение намного проще.

Comment: @Владимир а вам обязательно надо использовать именованные подмаски?

Comment: @Эдуард не обязательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблон в сборе: `[#.][^#.]+` Вместе с php будет выглядеть так:

```
$str = ".cl_name.cl_name2#send.cl_name3";

preg_match_all('~[#.][^#.]+~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '.cl_name' (length=8)
      1 => string '.cl_name2' (length=9)
      2 => string '#send' (length=5)
      3 => string '.cl_name3' (length=9)
```

> **UPD**: Для удобства группировки полученных значений можно использовать именованные подмаски:

```
$str = ".cl_name.cl_name2#send.cl_name3";

preg_match_all('~(?<id>#[^#.]+)|(?<class>\.[^#.]+)~', $str, $arr);
$arr = array_map('array_filter', $arr);

var_dump($arr['id'], $arr['class']);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  2 => string '#send' (length=5)

array (size=3)
  0 => string '.cl_name' (length=8)
  1 => string '.cl_name2' (length=9)
  3 => string '.cl_name3' (length=9)
```

Comment: Спасибо Эдуард, проблема решена. К сожалению не выучил ещё зачем нужна тильда ))

Comment: @Владимир тильда - это литерал _(обычный символ)_. В моём шаблоне тильда служит ограничителем шаблона.

Comment: @Владимир я оптимизировал шаблон )